# freopen function doesn't work

Tags: c, linux, io, redirect

I am working on redirecting the output from using `execvp` function to `out.txt` file in the current working directory. The access function returns 0, which indicates this is a writeable file and the value t should be in `stdout`.
However, `freopen` didn't write anything in the file and I wonder how that happens.

```
switch(pid = fork())
{
case -1:
    exit(0);

case 0:
    if(res)
        setenv("PARENT", res, 1);

    execvp(args[0], args);

}

int t = access("out.txt", W_OK);
printf("%d\n", t);

freopen("out.txt", "a", stdout);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: you are redirecting stdout to the file _after_ you have written and flushed (note the `'\n'`) it. There is nothing in the stdout stream that could be written to the file afterwards.

Comment: right, I solved the problem later by redirecting before the call of exec function. stdout basically have nothing as i call exec in the child process not in the parent process.